# How to resize the movable screen in proportion to the video screen behind it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

I am working on a website in which I want to resize the movable screen in proportion to the video screen behind it.

The video screen is behind the movable screen so if I resize the movable screen then the video screen should also get resized.

The HTML code for the **movable (draggable/resizable)** screen which I getting generated at the **run time** is:

**Javascript:**

The JS code **(which is not generated at the run time)** which is being used for the above html is:

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the JS code above so that whenever I resize the browser/video screen, the motion detection screen should also get resize.

Comment: Hi, could you please create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue you're trying to solve. There is some terminology you are using ('moveable screen', 'video screen') that would certainly be aided by a screenshot or workable prototype of what you're trying to achieve :)